# Configure error when installing php

Tags: linux, installation, php

When installing php I configure it like so:

```
./configure --prefix=/wwwroot/php --with-apxs2=/wwwroot/bin/apxs --with-configure-file-path=/wwwroot/php --with-mysql --with-gd
```

And a configure error shows up saying this:

```
xml2-config not found. Please check your libxml2 installation.
```

What's this all about? And how settle the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Not only do you need to install the [libxml2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/i386/libxml2/download) library, but you need to install the [libxml2-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/i386/libxml2-dev/download) package.  This package installs all the necessary headers so that your compile script will be able to find them and include them.  This is true of just about any other package that your compile script might complain about.  Look for a `[package name]-dev` package to install.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the libxml2 library first

Comment: Have installed it (http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/i386/libxml2/download), but still the same error.